# Unit testing ThrowIfCancellationRequested() was called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, mstest

I am currently using Moq to help with my unit testing however I ran in to an issue that I do not know how to resolve.

For example, say I would like to validate that `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` was called once per `Upload(` call

```
public UploadEngine(IUploader uploader)
{
     _uploader = uploader;
}

public void PerformUpload(CancellationToken token)
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    _uploader.Upload(token, "Foo");

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    _uploader.Upload(token, "Bar");
}
```

If `token` was a reference type I normally would do something like

```
[TestMethod()]
public void PerformUploadTest()
{
    var uploader = new Mock<IUploader>();
    var token = new Mock<CancellationToken>();

    int callCount = 0;

    uploader.Setup(a => a.Upload(token.Object, It.IsAny<string>())).Callback(() => callCount++);
    token.Setup(a => a.ThrowIfCancellationRequested());

    var engine = new UploadEngine(uploader.Object);
    engine.PerformUpload(token.Object);

    token.Verify(a => a.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), Times.Exactly(callCount));
}
```

However from what I can tell Moq does not support value types. What would be the correct way to test this, or is there no way to do what I want through Moq without boxing the `CancellationToken` inside a container first to be passed in to `PerformUpload(`?

Comment: Why not create a CancellationTokenSource and pass its .Token property to the uploader and decorate the test with the ExpectedException attribute?

Comment: Because I am not testing that if a cancellation is done it will get caught. I am testing that there is a 1:1 ratio of module calls to cancellation checks.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure you'll be able to mock the throwIf since it isn't virtual. You might have to wrap the token in your own interface and mock that.

Comment: You need a framework like Microsoft Fakes to mock non-virtual methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You pass the token to the Upload method already. Why don't you just throw the exception from within it instead of duplicating it for each call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably moved on from this, but it occurred to me that what you're trying to test doesn't really seem to make sense.  Testing that `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is called the same number of times as `Upload` does nothing to ensure that they have been called in the right sequence, which I'm assuming would actually be relevant in this case.  You wouldn't want code like this to pass, but I'm pretty sure it would:

```
_uploader.Upload(token, "Foo");

token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

_uploader.Upload(token, "Bar");
```

As has been said in the comments, the easiest way to get round this would be to push the `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` call into the `Upload` call.  Assuming that for whatever reason this isn't possible, I might take the following approach to testing your scenario.

Firstly, I'd encapsulate the functionality of checking to see if the cancellation had been requested and if not, calling an action into something testable.  At first thought, this might look like this:

```
public interface IActionRunner {
    void ExecIfNotCancelled(CancellationToken token, Action action);
}

public class ActionRunner : IActionRunner{
    public void ExecIfNotCancelled(CancellationToken token, Action action) {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        action();
    }
}
```

This can be fairly trivially tested with two tests.  One to check that action is called if the token isn't cancelled and one to validate that it isn't if it is cancelled.  These tests would look like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestActionRunnerExecutesAction() {
    bool run = false;
    var runner = new ActionRunner();
    var token = new CancellationToken();

    runner.ExecIfNotCancelled(token, () => run = true);

    // Validate action has been executed
    Assert.AreEqual(true, run);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestActionRunnerDoesNotExecuteIfCancelled() {
    bool run = false;
    var runner = new ActionRunner();
    var token = new CancellationToken(true);

    try {
        runner.ExecIfNotCancelled(token, () => run = true);
        Assert.Fail("Exception not thrown");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) {
        // Swallow only the expected exception
    }
    // Validate action hasn't been executed
    Assert.AreEqual(false, run);
}
```

I would then inject the `IActionRunner` into the `UploadEngine` and validate that it was being called correctly.  So, your `PerformUpload` method would change to:

```
public void PerformUpload(CancellationToken token) {
    _actionRunner.ExecIfNotCancelled(token, () => _uploader.Upload(token, "Foo"));
    _actionRunner.ExecIfNotCancelled(token, () => _uploader.Upload(token, "Bar"));
}
```

You can then write a pair of tests to validate `PerformUpload`.  The first checks that if an `ActionRunner` mock has been setup to execute the supplied action then `Upload` is called at least once.  The second test validates that if the `ActionRunner` mock has been setup to ignore the action, then `Upload` isn't called.  This essentially ensures that *all* `Upload` calls in the method are done via the `ActionRunner`.  These tests look  like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestUploadCallsMadeThroughActionRunner() {
    var uploader = new Mock<IUploader>();
    var runner = new Mock<IActionRunner>();
    var token = new CancellationToken();

    int callCount = 0;

    uploader.Setup(a => a.Upload(token, It.IsAny<string>())).Callback(() => callCount++);
    // Use callback to invoke actions supplied to runner
    runner.Setup(x => x.ExecIfNotCancelled(token, It.IsAny<Action>()))
          .Callback<CancellationToken, Action>((tok,act)=>act());

    var engine = new UploadEngine(uploader.Object, runner.Object);
    engine.PerformUpload(token);

    Assert.IsTrue(callCount > 0);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestNoUploadCallsMadeThroughWithoutActionRunner() {
    var uploader = new Mock<IUploader>();
    var runner = new Mock<IActionRunner>();
    var token = new CancellationToken();

    int callCount = 0;

    uploader.Setup(a => a.Upload(token, It.IsAny<string>())).Callback(() => callCount++);
    // NOP callback on runner prevents uploader action being run
    runner.Setup(x => x.ExecIfNotCancelled(token, It.IsAny<Action>()))
          .Callback<CancellationToken, Action>((tok, act) => { });

    var engine = new UploadEngine(uploader.Object, runner.Object);
    engine.PerformUpload(token);

    Assert.AreEqual(0, callCount);
}
```

There would obviously be other tests that you might want to write for your `UploadEngine` but they seem out of scope for the current question...